Unreachable Catch Block for IsEmptyException and IsFullException. These exceptions are never thrown from the try statement body
In my ArrayQueueTest.java file, I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. I get the same error, which is

unreachable catch block for IsEmptyException and IsFullException

I have tried everything from double checking imports/packages to make sure everything has the correct path. The files have a correct path. I'm at the end of the road here with this assignment, as I have no idea what is going wrong.
package apps;

import adts.ArrayQueue;
import exceptions.IsFullException;
import exceptions.IsEmptyException;

public class ArrayQueueTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayQueue<String> queue = new ArrayQueue<>(3);
        try {
            queue.enqueue("A");
            queue.enqueue("B");
            queue.enqueue("C");
            System.out.println(queue);
            queue.enqueue("D");
        }
        catch (IsFullException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IsEmptyException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("Dequeue: " + queue.dequeue());
            System.out.println(queue);
            queue.dequeue();
            queue.dequeue();
            queue.dequeue();
        }
        catch (IsFullException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IsEmptyException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


package adts;

import interfaces.QueueInterface;
import exceptions.IsFullException;
import exceptions.IsEmptyException;

public class ArrayQueue<E> implements QueueInterface<E> {
    protected E[] queue;  
    protected int front = 0;
    protected int rear = 0;
    protected int size = 0;

    protected final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 5;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayQueue() {
        queue = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayQueue(int capacity) {
        queue = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
    }


    @Override
    public void enqueue(E element) throws IsFullException {
        if (isFull()) {
            System.out.println("Queue is full, throwing IsFullException"); // 
            throw new IsFullException("Out, out, brief candle! The queue is ful");          
        }
        queue[rear] = element;
        rear = (rear + 1) % queue.length;
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public E dequeue() throws IsEmptyException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Queue is empty, throwing IsEmptyException"); //   
            throw new IsEmptyException("The queue is empty! All we have is     time!");
        }
        E temp = queue[front];
        queue[front] = null;
        front = (front + 1) % queue.length;
        size--;
        return temp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFull() {
        return size == queue.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder qStr = new StringBuilder("\nQueue: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            qStr.append(queue[(front + i) % queue.length]).append(" ");
        }
        return qStr.toString();
    }
}


package exceptions;

public class IsEmptyException extends Exception
{
    public IsEmptyException(String message) 
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
package exceptions;

public class IsFullException  extends Exception
{
    public IsFullException(String message) 
    {
        super(message);
    }
}


package interfaces;

import exceptions.IsEmptyException;
import exceptions.IsFullException;

public interface QueueInterface<E> {

    void enqueue(E element) throws IsFullException; // add an element to the queue - always at the end of the queue

    E dequeue() throws IsEmptyException; // remove and return the front of the queue

    boolean isEmpty();

    boolean isFull();

}


You should stick to hierarchy, even with Exceptions: So it's usually better to inherit from a specific Exception. Better write IsEmptyException extends IllegalStateException or something along those lines. I noticed that especially when writing backends, as handling of Exceptions gets way better, once you have 'families' of exceptions, like ClientSideException, that you need to handle completely different from most other 'internal' Exceptions. Maybe even have the chain: IllegalStateException - QueueException - ArrayQueueException - IsFullException, whatever makes sense in your library.

Method enqueue does not throw IsEmptyException. In the try block, you are only calling method enqueue, hence that try block can only throw IsFullException (and not IsEmptyException). Likewise, in the other try block, you are only calling method dequeue which only throws IsEmptyException, hence that try block cannot throw IsFullException.

Your enqueue method doesn't declare it throws the IsEmptyException, only the IsFullException, so you get this error when trying to catch this error on a block that only has a bunch of enqueue calls.
Similarly, the dequeue method doesn't declare the IsFullException, so you get this error on a block that only has a bunch of dequeue calls.
You could safely remove these wrong catch clauses:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayQueue<String> queue = new ArrayQueue<>(3); 

    try {
        queue.enqueue("A");  
        queue.enqueue("B");  
        queue.enqueue("C");  
        System.out.println(queue);
   
        queue.enqueue("D"); 
    } catch (IsFullException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }

    try {       
        System.out.println("Dequeue: " + queue.dequeue());  
        System.out.println(queue);
    
        queue.dequeue();
        queue.dequeue();
        queue.dequeue(); 
    } catch (IsEmptyException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }
}

Or unify the try blocks:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayQueue<String> queue = new ArrayQueue<>(3); 

    try {
        queue.enqueue("A");  
        queue.enqueue("B");  
        queue.enqueue("C");  
        System.out.println(queue);
   
        queue.enqueue("D"); 

        System.out.println("Dequeue: " + queue.dequeue());  
        System.out.println(queue);
    
        queue.dequeue();
        queue.dequeue();
        queue.dequeue(); 
    } catch (IsFullException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    } catch (IsEmptyException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }
}


Note that if you unify the try-blocks, then you'll never perform the dequeues if an enqueue threw an exception. That may or may not be desirable.
